# Node.js module.exports through interface

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have a module which is structured like this:
(Where Folder is prefixed with `-` and file with `|`)

```
- MyModule
 |index.js
 - Lib
  |database.js
  |register.js
  |table.js
```

The *index.js* file should be an interface file which provides the api's of the module, that are in Lib...

So my *index.js* looks like this:

```
var register  = require('./lib/register');
var table     = require('./lib/table');

module.exports = {
  register        : register.addNewUser,
  createNewTable  : table.createTable,
  dropTable       : table.dropTable
}
```

So I can call my Module in my app with:

```
var myModule = require('./myModule');
```

and then for example:

```
myModule.register; //registers a new user...
```

Something special is *database.js*. It looks like this:

```
var mysql     = require('mysql');

module.exports = {
  createPool: function(options) {
    console.log('creating Pool ...')
    return module.exports.pool = mysql.createPool(options);
  }
}
```

It creates a mysql pool ([with geisendoerfers mysql module](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql)) and makes this pool accessible for other files in my module with:

```
var pool = require('./database').pool;
```

It is once initiated in app.js:

```
var options   = {
  host     : 'host',
  user     : 'user',
  password : 'pwd',
  database : 'database'
}

var makePool      = require('./MyModule/lib/database').createPool(options);
```

This works fine!
But now I tried to get the function `createPool` in the *index.js* file as well, so I can call

```
var options = {...}
var makePool = require('./MyModule').createPool(options);
```

I tried this with this approach in *index.js*:

```
var database  = require('./lib/database');
var register  = require('./lib/register');
var table     = require('./lib/table');

module.exports = {
  createPool      : database.createPool,
  register        : register.addNewUser,
  createNewTable  : table.createTable,
  dropTable       : table.dropTable
}
```

Now something strange for me.
This works in *App.js* as it should:

```
var options   = {...}

var makePool      = require('./myModule').createPool(options);
var pool          = require('./myModule/lib/database').pool;

pool.getConnection(function(err, connection){
  connection.query('SELECT 12 + 8 AS solution', function(err, result){
    console.log(result);
    connection.release();
  });
});
```

But this does not work for example in *register.js*.
Pool is undefined there...

```
var pool          = require('./database').pool;
console.log(pool);
```

How is the common design pattern for something like this?
best martin

Comment: I don't have time to write a full answer right now. But from the first look the `register.js` is _required/evaluated_ before `App.js` calls `createPool` and therefore `pool` is `undefined`. Structuring your module that way isn't a good idea as it depends on the loading/execution order of the individual files.

Comment: Thank you for that hint. Can you give me a recommendation to read about how i should structure those things? The idea behind is, to easily configure a module in app.js. Like the mysql-session extension does for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand why `pool` is `undefined` you need to look through your code step by step.

**1.**  In you `App.js` you have this line:

```
var makePool = require('./myModule').createPool(options);
```

Which will first include `myModule` and then  calls `createPool` on the result.

**2.** In the `index.js` of your `myModule`  you have the line:

```
var register  = require('./lib/register')
```

This line is called before the `module.exports`  of this file is returned, which is before the  `.createPool(options)` in the `App.js` is called.

**3.** In the `register.js` you have the lines:

```
 var pool          = require('./database').pool;
 console.log(pool);
```

But at the time you try to get the `require('./database').pool` it does not exists as `createPool` wasn't called at that time.

**4.**  After everything is done in the `myModule` the `createPool` is called and the `pool` is created.

---

**So how could you solve this?**

One way would be to restructure your code so that the access to `.pool` would always contain the something. e.g. by calling `require('./lib/database').createPool(options)` in your `App.js` before you call `require('./myModule')`.

But this isn't the best solution, as you need to write into your documentation that this order is required to make your code working.

A better way would be to use some kind of async approach to request the pool, instead of directly accessing the property.

Either using callbacks:

```
require('./lib/database')
.getPool(function(err, pool) {
    //do something with the pool or show the error message
});
```

Or using Promises (e.g. [bluebird](https://www.npmjs.org/package/bluebird)):

```
require('./lib/database').getPool()
.then(function(pool) {
   //do something with the pool
})
.catch(function(e) {
   //do something in case of the error
});
```

You for sure need to implement some logic for your `getPool`, depending on the use case this could be either if no `pool` exists at the time `getPool`  then continue with an error directly or you would wait until you the pool is created and then continue with the success state.

Comment: This... answer... is .... awesome !!!! Thank you, clarified much :-) I will use the callbacks, i think...

Comment: @marschro As you will use async code all the time in node I personally  would recommend to learn how _Promise_  works and how to use them correctly.

Answer (score 0):

the answer is simple , the pool is not created in register.js

```
module.exports = {
  createPool: function(options) {
    console.log('creating Pool ...')
    return module.exports.pool = mysql.createPool(options);
  }
}
```

you need to call createPool first,as you wrote in your script.

Comment: Thank you. That seems like, yes. But why is the pool created, when I run it directly with var pool = require('./myModule/lib/database').createPoll(options). This works!